# Datagrid inside another datagrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I need to show a datagrid inside another datagrid. I have done this by using RowDetailsTemplate and adding a datagrid in it. But the main problem is, I need to show multiple inner grids at same time. When the selected item is changed, the inner datagrid of the previous selected item is not displayed. Any suggestions :(

I am using expander control to show/hide the details. When expander control is opened, I am changing the RowDetailstemplate's visiblity to true.

When the selected item is changed, RowDetailsTemplate of the current selected row is only being visible if I expand the expander.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer,

```
   private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    int rowIndex = this.DataGridForEvents.SelectedIndex;
    List<DataGridRow> rows = GetRows();
    rows[rowIndex].DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

private void Expander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
int rowIndex = this.DataGridForEvents.SelectedIndex;
List<DataGridRow> rows = GetRows();
rows[rowIndex].DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}



public List<DataGridRow>  GetRows()
{
List<DataGridRow> rows = new List<DataGridRow>();
foreach (var rowItem in this.DataGridForEvents.ItemsSource)
{
this.DataGridForEvents.ScrollIntoView(rowItem, this.DataGridForEvents.Columns.Last());
FrameworkElement el = this.DataGridForEvents.Columns.Last().GetCellContent(rowItem);
DataGridRow row = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(el.Parent as FrameworkElement);
if (row != null)
rows.Add(row);
}
return rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the visibility of the row details of each row using the [`DataGridRow.DetailsVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.detailsvisibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property.

Perhaps you also need to change [`DataGrid.RowDetailsVisibilityMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailsvisibilitymode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to another value than `VisibleWhenSelected`